# Code::Blocks, glut, and OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, codeblocks, glut

I am trying to update an old C language 2-D game named Boomtown (an arcade-style Bomberman knockoff!) that uses glut and OpenGL and no longer compiles with the latest version of Code::Blocks.  I am trying to add the source files into the src/ folder of the project itself but I'm getting a crash.  Any help is much appreciated! I'll try to include as much info about the project as I can.

**Project layout:**
Name of project folder: boomtown
Located inside boomtown\src:
   boomtown.cbp
   include\
   lib\
   old version of glut32.lib (Not sure exactly how this was used in the old setup)

**Other info**
OS: Windows 7 64-bit (but trying to set the project up using the x86 glut resources)
CodeBlocks Version: 12.11
Compiler: GNU GCC Compiler

Here is what I have done so far:

**[Glut]**

- Downloaded glut32.dll glut.h and glut32.lib
- Added glut32.dll and glut.h into the boomtown\src\include folder
- Added glut32.lib into the boomtown\src\lib folder
- Replaced old glut32.lib with new (Just in case)

**[OpenGL]**

- Added SFML source into the boomtown\src\include folder
- Added SFML library files into the boomtown\src\lib folder

**[CodeBlocks]**

- Project->Build Options->Linker settings->Link libraries: lib\glut32.lib and all SFML.a files there
- Project->Build Options->Linker settings->Search directories->Compiler/Linker: \boomtown\src\
- Added boomtown\src\include\glut.h to Project workspace
- Added boomtown\src\include\SFML header files into Project workspace

When I build and run I get no errors (woohoo!), but a blank debug window comes up and I get this:

```
boomtown.exe - Application Error  
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000be).  Click OK to close the application.
```

If everything works correctly, the game should pop up rather than the Application Error. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to make sure that your libraries are linked in the proper order:

The correct order is:

```
    -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32
```

Of course -lwinmm and -lgdi32 may not be required.   glut32 requires glu32 which in-turn requires opengl32

Try setting your Project->Build Options->Linker settings->Link libraries: to

```
lib\glut32.lib lib\glu32.lib lib\opengl32.lib
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed Masud, I _think_ I have the errors worked out after adding in SFML to handle the gl stuff, but I get an immediate crash when I try to run the .exe.  Any ideas?